# R: Line chart is overlapping with text labels

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I have created one line graph using plotly in Shiny. Now, in the line graph if I wish to add labels to they are overlapping with the line which makes it difficult to understand.

I am using the following code:

```
     a = paste("$",prettyNum(de$Amount, big.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE), sep = "")
      f <- list(

        size = 14,
        color = "Black",
        fontface="bold"
      )
      xQuartAxis <- list(
        title = "Month")
      yQuartAxis <- list(
        title = "Amount in $")
      plot_ly(
        x = as.vector(de$Month),
        y = de$Amount,
        text = paste(a), hoverinfo = "text", textinfo="text",showlegend = FALSE,
        name = "Amount Paid",
        mode = "lines+text"
      )%>%

        layout(title=paste("Monthly Amount paid by", clientName,"for the year",selectedYear, sep = " ") ,titlefont =f,t = 150,  xaxis = xQuartAxis, yaxis = yQuartAxis)
})
```

I am getting this output:

[image: Click To View Output]

**Kindly tell me how can I separate the text from line graph for better visibility?**

Thanks :)

Comment: Try `geom_label` for a solid background, or `ggrepel::geom_text_repel`.

Comment: Can I add geom_label in plotly graphs?

Comment: Yikes, I'm tired. But yes, actually, if you use `ggplotly`. Or just show the information in a popup, which might be more natural for plotly.

Comment: You need to create some difference between the line's y-values and the labels' y-values, but I have to be done manually... For examples, you can pass to the y parameter of `geom_text` (visually based on your scale): `geom_text(x=as.vector(de$Month), y = de$Amount + c(+50, -50, +50, -50, +50, -50, +50, -50, +100, +50, +100, -50), ...)`

Comment: @Leo can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not getting this.

Comment: Instead of moving the labels up or down, I'd suggest making the numbers stand out relative to the line. First, make the line transparent (alpha=0.2 or so). The line will still be visible to guide your eye, but the numbers will be highlighted. Second, truncate the numbers to thousands to match the y-scale. You don't need a five-digit mantissa with two decimals places. Instead do `a = paste0("$", sprintf("%1.1f", de$Amount/1000))`.

Comment: Does plotly has any function named as "alpha" for making the line transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest making the numbers stand out relative to the line. First, make the line transparent (say, alpha=0.2). The line will still be visible to guide your eye, but the numbers will be highlighted.

Second, truncate the numbers to thousands to match the y-scale. You don't need to display so many digits for the point markers.

Here's a `ggplotly` version, as I'm not sure how to separately set the opacity for the text markers and the line with `plot_ly`. You can add, say, `opacity=0.3` inside `plot_ly()`, but that makes the text markers transparent as well.

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# Fake data
set.seed(395875)
de = data.frame(Month=factor(month.abb, levels=month.abb), Amount=rnorm(12, 12000, 1000))

ggplotly(
  ggplot(de, aes(Month,Amount)) +
    geom_line(aes(group=1), alpha=0.2, color="blue") + 
    geom_text(aes(label=paste0("$", sprintf("%1.1f", Amount/1000))), size=3.5) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(de$Amount)), breaks=seq(0,15000,5000), 
                       labels=paste0("$",seq(0,15000,5000)/1000,"k")) +
    labs(y="Amount ($000)")
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yes I just found in plot_ly opacity do the transparency work. Thanks for your valuable time and advice.